# Kivy: Custom button not updating with self.state change

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to create a GUI and after looking at various posts here I'm still stumped. My problem is that the custom button I've made to reflect the state of a GPIO push button is not updating its appearance when I set `self.state` to something different. I think it might be related to object constructions, but I can't figure out how to fix it.

#### main.py

```py
import kivy
kivy.require('1.11.1')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.core.window import Window
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

# make app run in fullscreen mode
Window.fullscreen = 'auto'  # uses display's current resolution

# Set up GPIO
ok_btn_pin = 4
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(ok_btn_pin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.add_event_detect(ok_btn_pin, GPIO.BOTH)    #detect if GPIO.RISING or GPIO.FALLING occur


class GPIOButton(Button):

    btn_gpio_pin = NumericProperty(-1)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(GPIOButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        print("GPIOButton __init__ called")
        print("btn_gpio_pin =", self.btn_gpio_pin)

    def update(self, dt):
        #print("GPIOButton update() called")
        if GPIO.input(self.btn_gpio_pin) == GPIO.HIGH and GPIO.event_detected(self.btn_gpio_pin):
            self.state = 'down'            
            print("Pin", self.btn_gpio_pin, self.state)
        elif GPIO.input(self.btn_gpio_pin) == GPIO.LOW and GPIO.event_detected(self.btn_gpio_pin):
            self.state = 'normal'
            print("Pin", self.btn_gpio_pin, self.state)


class LeftSidebar(FloatLayout):

    ok_btn = GPIOButton(btn_gpio_pin = ok_btn_pin)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LeftSidebar, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        print("LeftSidebar __init__ called")

    def update(self, dt):
        #print("LeftSidebar update() called")
        self.ok_btn.update(dt)


class LifterGUI(FloatLayout):

    left_sidebar = LeftSidebar()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LifterGUI, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        print("LifterGUI __init__ called")
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0/10.0)

    def update(self, dt):
        #print("LifterGUI update() called")
        self.left_sidebar.update(dt)


class LifterApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.root = LifterGUI()
        return self.root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        LifterApp().run()
    finally:
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

#### lifter.kv

```py
#:kivy 1.11.1
#:set camera_width_percent 4.0/5.0
#:set sidebar_width_percent (1.0 - camera_width_percent) / 2.0

<LeftSidebar>:
    ok_btn_button: ok_btn

    #:set num_btns 10.0
    
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 1, 0, 0
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    GPIOButton:
        id: ok_btn
        btn_gpio_pin: 4
        text: "ok"
        size_hint: (1.0, 1.0/num_btns)
        pos_hint: {'top': 1.0/num_btns}
    

<LifterGUI>:
    left_sidebar_widget: left_sidebar

    LeftSidebar: 
        id: left_sidebar
        size_hint: (sidebar_width_percent, 1.0)
```

#### Terminal output

I click the GPIO push button 3 times, which prints to the terminal but doesn't update the GPIOButton appearance. **Note that LeftSidebar __init__ and GPIOButton __init__ each get called twice for some reason** (I think once from my class attribute declarations and once from the kv file but I'm not sure). I've tried using ObjectProperty(None) instead for ok_btn and left_sidebar to see if that helps, but  then I just get `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update'` errors so I'm not sure that's the correct approach.

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/pi/.kivy/logs/kivy_20-09-30_53.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.3 (default, Dec 20 2019, 18:57:59) 
[GCC 8.3.0]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "/usr/bin/python3"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2(['text_pango'] ignored)
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2(['window_egl_rpi'] ignored)
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <sdl2>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'3.1 Mesa 19.3.2'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'VMware, Inc.'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'llvmpipe (LLVM 9.0.1, 128 bits)'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 1
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'1.40'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <8192>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
GPIOButton __init__ called
btn_gpio_pin = 4
LeftSidebar __init__ called
LeftSidebar __init__ called
GPIOButton __init__ called
btn_gpio_pin = -1
LifterGUI __init__ called
[INFO   ] [ProbeSysfs  ] device match: /dev/input/event0
[INFO   ] [MTD         ] Read event from </dev/input/event0>
[INFO   ] [ProbeSysfs  ] device match: /dev/input/event0
[INFO   ] [HIDInput    ] Read event from </dev/input/event0>
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [HIDMotionEvent] using <WaveShare WS170120>
[INFO   ] [MTD         ] </dev/input/event0> range position X is 0 - 800
[INFO   ] [HIDMotionEvent] <WaveShare WS170120> range ABS X position is 0 - 800
[INFO   ] [MTD         ] </dev/input/event0> range position Y is 0 - 480
[INFO   ] [HIDMotionEvent] <WaveShare WS170120> range ABS Y position is 0 - 480
[INFO   ] [MTD         ] </dev/input/event0> range touch major is 0 - 0
[INFO   ] [HIDMotionEvent] <WaveShare WS170120> range ABS pressure is 0 - 255
[INFO   ] [MTD         ] </dev/input/event0> range touch minor is 0 - 0
[INFO   ] [HIDMotionEvent] <WaveShare WS170120> range position X is 0 - 800
[INFO   ] [MTD         ] </dev/input/event0> range pressure is 0 - 255
[INFO   ] [HIDMotionEvent] <WaveShare WS170120> range position Y is 0 - 480
[INFO   ] [MTD         ] </dev/input/event0> axes invertion: X is 0, Y is 0
[INFO   ] [HIDMotionEvent] <WaveShare WS170120> range pressure is 0 - 255
[INFO   ] [MTD         ] </dev/input/event0> rotation set to 0
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
Pin 4 down
Pin 4 normal
Pin 4 down
Pin 4 normal
Pin 4 down
Pin 4 normal
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `__init__()` of `GPIOButton` is being called twice. Once when your `build()` method is called and `self.root = LifterGUI()` is executed. This creates the `GPIOButton` that appears in your GUI via the `kv` rules. The `__init__()` method is called again when `ok_btn = GPIOButton(btn_gpio_pin = ok_btn_pin)` is executed in your `LeftSidebar` class. This second call creates an instance of `GPIOButton` that does not appear in your GUI, but it is the one that is referenced in the `update()` method.

Since you already have setup a reference to the `GPIOButton` in your `kv`, you can modify the `LeftSidebar` class to use that reference:

```
class LeftSidebar(FloatLayout):

    ok_btn_button = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LeftSidebar, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        print("LeftSidebar __init__ called")

    def update(self, dt):
        #print("LeftSidebar update() called")
        self.ok_btn_button.update(dt)
```

The `ok_btn_button` in your `kv` and the `ok_btn_button` in the `LeftSidebar` set up a reference to the `GPIOButton` that is built in the `kv`. With that you can refer to the button using `self.ok_btn_button` in the `LeftSidebar` class.

Note that you have nearly the exact same error in your `LifterGUI`.

Comment: This works, thanks. I do find it a little confusing that either `ok_btn_button = ObjectProperty(None) .... self.ok_btn_button.update(dt)` works, or `#no object declaration in main.py .... self.ids.ok_btn.update(dt)` works, but not `self.ids.ok_btn_button.update(dt)`. I originally had dissimilar names so I could better probe how the kv language works, but perhaps it's simpler to just have `ok_btn_button: ok_btn_button` for easier maintainability haha. Thanks again

Comment: You can actually leave out the `ok_btn_button = ObjectProperty(None)` because the `ok_btn_button: ok_btn` in the `kv` will create the `ObjectProperty` if it does not already exist. I prefer to explicitly create the `ObjectProperty` in the python code for clarity.